# Why Interval not stopped after condition?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm trying to remove the timer after some conditions but the countdown still running even when the interval is cleared.

I have tried changing switch/case to if/else and still does not work.

```js
let time = 15000;
const interval = setInterval(async () => {
    switch (true) {
        case message.toLowerCase() === answer.toLowerCase():
            return clearInterval(interval);

        case time <= 0:
            clearInterval(interval);

            embed.setDescription(`The answer is: ${bold(answer)}`);

            await message.edit({ embeds: [embed] });
        break;

        default:
            time -= 1000;

            embed.setDescription(
                `${pertanyaan}${codeBlock(`(${time / 1000}s remaining)`)}`,
            );

            await message.edit({ embeds: [embed] });
        break;
    }
}, 1000);
```

The code above is about quiz. I want to stop the interval after 15 seconds or after the answer is correct.

The code is reach the first case

```
case message.toLowerCase() === answer.toLowerCase():
    return clearInterval(interval);
```

but immediately run the default one.

## Edit

I change my code to something like this, I think it's correct.

```js
let time = 15000;
const checkAnswer = () => {
    if (time <= 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);

        embed.setDescription(`The answer is: ${bold(answer))}`);

        return message.edit({ embeds: [embed] });
    } else if (message.toLowerCase() === answer.toLowerCase()) {
        clearInterval(interval);

        embed.setDescription(
            `Congratulations! Your answer is correct\nThe answer is: ${bold(
                answer,
            )}`,
        );

        return message.edit({ embeds: [embed] });
    } else {
        time -= 1000;

        embed.setDescription(
            `${pertanyaan}${codeBlock(`(${time / 1000}s remaining)`)}`,
        );

        return message.edit({ embeds: [embed] });
    }
};

const interval = setInterval(() => checkAnswer(), 1000);
```

Comment: Why did you mark the callback async when you're not using await? Why are you returning anything? It's a callback. How do you know the condition is working? Are you calling this code more than once so multiple intervals get created but only one gets cleared? Etc, etc. Need more detail please, no way we can elp you with no more than you posted.

Comment: I am not sure whether the syntax is correct. is "true" a variable? is it a reserved word in javascript?

Comment: @TheKNVB Its valid - you can pass in anything into a `switch`, if it's already a value it will get matched. It does make for a confusing bit of code here, as it's switching but it feels like a simple `if` statement would work better to avoid confusion over what branch it will access...

Comment: I have not ever seen use the switch ..... case in this way. The code inspires me very much.

Comment: Do not use a switch as an if statement. It is bad practice.

Comment: If the interval is still running after it is cleared, people typically have more than one interval set or they somehow wrote over the id. Is that code where you define the interval not in any click or load event? How do you start it?