# Remove redundant if object javascript

Tags: javascript, object

Hello I have an object that I want to browse and when a value is equal to true I fill an array.
My code works but I don’t think it’s good to put so much if.

```
daysOfWeek: {
      lundi: true,
      mardi: true,
      mercredi: true,
      jeudi: false,
      vendredi: true,
      samedi: true,
      dimanche: true
    }
```

```
 let days = []

    if (daysOfWeek != null) {
        if (daysOfWeek.lundi === true) {
            days.push(2)
        }
        if (daysOfWeek.mardi === true) {
            days.push(3)
        }
        if (daysOfWeek.mercredi === true) {
            days.push(4)
        }
        if (daysOfWeek.jeudi === true) {
            days.push(5)
        }
        if (daysOfWeek.vendredi === true) {
            days.push(6)
        }
        if (daysOfWeek.samedi === true) {
            days.push(7)
        }
        if (daysOfWeek.dimanche === true) {
            days.push(1)
        }
    }
    return days
```

`days = [2,3,4,6,7,1]`

I tried the switch/case but it doesn’t work for conditions.

Does anyone have another solution for me to explore?

Comment: You may refer to the following page for the special usage of the switch/case.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74567878/why-interval-not-stopped-after-condition

Comment: how will that help @TheKNVB?

Comment: why would the result be `days = [2,3,4,5,6,7]` surely it's `[2,3,4,6,7,1]` for that data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78072625/23487734) suggestion.

The number must be from `0` (Sunday) to `6` (Saturday).
In some locales, it may be `0` (Monday) to `6` (Sunday).

[moment weekday](https://github.com/moment/momentjs.com/blob/master/docs/moment/02-get-set/07-weekday.md)

But if you want to set `1` as the first day of the week, I would suggest the code below

```js
const daysOfWeek =  {
  lundi: true,
  mardi: true,
  mercredi: true,
  jeudi: false,
  vendredi: true,
  samedi: true,
  dimanche: true
}

const TOTAL_DAYS_OF_WEEK = 7;
const IS_SUNDAY_A_FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK = true;
const FIRST_DAY_START_WITH = 1;

const result = [];
Object.values(daysOfWeek).forEach((value, index) => {
    if(value) {
        const dayOfWeek = (index + IS_SUNDAY_A_FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK) % TOTAL_DAYS_OF_WEEK + FIRST_DAY_START_WITH;
        result.push(dayOfWeek);
    }
});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. I suggest you order and number the days Sunday:0 and Saturday:6 to match JavaScript's order and numbering. Otherwise add one to the index as I do below.
   Note that your example output did not match the object values
2. Use reduce:

```js
const daysOfWeek =  {
  dimanche: true,
  lundi: true,
  mardi: true,
  mercredi: true,
  jeudi: false,
  vendredi: true,
  samedi: true
}

// curr is the true/false. I use && to shortcut and the comma operator to return the accumulator
const days = Object.values(daysOfWeek)
  .reduce((acc, curr, index) => (curr && acc.push(index + 1), acc), []);
  
  console.log(days)
```

Comment: Thank you it's good for me , and thank for explain to me